# replace numeric values in column dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im new using python.
I have a dataframe with 3 columns `(id, name, description)`, My `dataframe` contains as example these rows `('id1', 'paul', 'tmp123'), ('id2', 'laura', 'vi34jay')`. I want to replace the numeric characters of my column description by `"TT"`.

**expected output**

```
('id1', 'paul', 'tmpTTT'), ('id2', 'laura', 'viTTjay')
```

Does anyone knows how to do?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with `\d` for match digit:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'description': ['tmp123', 'vi34jay']})

df['description'] = df['description'].replace('\d', 'T', regex=True)
print(df)
  description
0      tmpTTT
1     viTTjay
```